# How to merge a list of dictionaries into a dictionary key:list pairing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I'm trying to merge a list of dictionaries with shared keys into a key:list pairing where the list contains all the values. The bottom code does it, but it's very ugly. I vaguely remember being able to use reduce on a list of dictionaries to accomplish this, but I am at a loss.

```
  1 dictionaries =  [{key.split(',')[0]:key.split(',')[1]} for key in open('test.data').read().splitlines()]
  2 print dictionaries
  3 new_dict = {}
  4 for line in open('test.data').read().splitlines():                                                                                  
  5     key, value = line.split(',')[0], line.split(',')[1]
  6     if not key in new_dict:
  7         new_dict[key] = []
  8     new_dict[key].append(value)
  9 print new_dict
```

output:

```
[{'abc': ' a'}, {'abc': ' b'}, {'cde': ' c'}, {'cde': ' d'}]
{'cde': [' c', ' d'], 'abc': [' a', ' b']}
```

test.data contains:

```
abc, a
abc, b
cde, c
cde, d
```

Comment: Code that works is beautiful.

Comment: @wwii: code that works is *fine*. Beautiful codes are pleasing to eyes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `for` loop could be simplified using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) as:

```
from collections import defaultdict 

new_dict = defaultdict(list)

for line in open('test.data').readlines(): # `.readlines()` will work same as
                                           # `.read().splitlines()`
    key, value = line.split(', ')  # <-- unwrapped and automatically assigned
    new_dict[key].append(value)
```